# why the self-reference struct need pin?

Tags: rust

I knew what pin does, and how it works, but the self-reference object can't be moved, also can't get &mut ref.

```
struct SelfRef<'a> {
    s: String,
    s_ref: Option<&'a str>
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = SelfRef {
        s: "hello".to_owned(),
        s_ref: None
    };
    a.s_ref = Some(&a.s);
    // let b = a; // compile error, can't move
}
```

if s_ref is a pointer, I think the pin is needed. but this has complied and run normally

```
use std::ptr::null;

struct SelfRef {
    s: String,
    s_ref: *const String
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = SelfRef {
        s: "hello world".to_owned(),
        s_ref: null(),
    };
    a.s_ref = &a.s;
    let b = a;
    unsafe {
        println!("{:?}", *b.s_ref);
    }
}
```

Comment: you use raw pointer and you are surprise it's compile ? Why it's should not compile ?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#example-self-referential-struct or https://github.com/jpernst/rental

Comment: it should compile, but why can run not fault?

Comment: because UB is UB, an undefined behavior is my nature... undefined, you get lucky this time.

Comment: What's the question?